# ts(7016)Could not find a declaration file for module 'cloudinary-react'. Try `npm i --save-dev @types/cloudinary-react` if it exists or add a new...?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cloudinary

So I am working with typescript right now in react. For some reason when I import the following

```
import { Image } from 'cloudinary-react';
```

I am getting this error

**Could not find a declaration file for module 'cloudinary-react'.** 'c:/Users/../../../../../client/node_modules/cloudinary-react/dist/cloudinary-react.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
**Try `npm i --save-dev @types/cloudinary-react` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'cloudinary-react';`ts(7016)**

1. I did install **npm install cloudinary-react** in client
2. I tried npm i --save-dev @types/cloudinary-react, but I am getting the following error
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7St1w.png)
3. I tried adding `"noImplicitAny": false` in **tsconfig.json** and no luck there either

Can't get it to work anyone has any solution to this? I tried many "Solutions" posted online but none of them work

Answer (score 0):

The `cloudinary-react` package does not support typescript.

However, Cloudinary has a newer React SDK (v2), which does support TS -
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/react2_integration

Here is an example project - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-sdk-sample-xhzek?file=/src/index.tsx